# Flutter doctor problem "Android Studio not found" in Android Studio Portable setup

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, sdk

I created a portable installation of Android Studio. That works (e:\android)
I installed Flutter in e:\src (this flutter configuration has worked)
I want to get this running

Flutter doctor -v gives me the common error:

> Android Studio (not installed)
> Android Studio not found

I did the following

- edit the PATH variabel
- reinstalled the plugins in A. Studio

I am trying to figure out what exactly causes the error. I played with ANDROID_HOME settings but I'm not sure what the exact location shoud be based on e:/android

An explanation of the cause or a good solution would be welcome. All threads I can find refer to regular AS installations, not to portable installation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

steps to reproduce config your android sdk

```
flutter config --android-sdk /media/user/androidsdk
```

export your android sdk to path

```
 export PATH="$PATH:/media/user//androidsdk"
```

now you can use an editor of your choice

> Android Studio (not installed) Android Studio not found

If youre a begginer to flutter it should not make you worry that your installation is incomplete .You can use an editor of your liking vscode, etc...

to read more on this check this issues https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25719

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27283

PS i'm on linux

Comment: Thnx Griffins, I know this advice. Problem is I don't know the correct subfolder in android studio portable. I can't find folder androidsdk in my android folder

Comment: if youre on wndows its on appdata

Comment: ...not when using Android Mobile. I gave up. Reinstalled Android on W10 and everything works. Thanks for the help